# Unable to Build the project after gradle :2.1.0

Tags: android

I was trying to implement google gcm in my app.For that, I require google play services to be added.All setup has made as required.But while building getting error like this:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.

> Unable to delete directory:    /media/Development/Projects/Source/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/AARPNow/oplytic_sdk-1.0/unspecified/jars

If I remove that oplytic_sdk-1.0 library and then same error will pointing to other dependencies.

Does anybody know whats wrong with my gradle?

Comment: check settings.gradle if its still there remove it.

Comment: i had removed it checked, no use

Comment: Try manually delete entire build directory. If some files are still in use, restart PC and try again. After deleting it, open your project and do Build -> Clean project

Comment: tried everything, doesn't work